# Custom styling of SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to change default color of tracker when state of SwitchPreferenceCompat is 'off'.
thumb : the circular button part of switch
tracker : the bar part of switch

I tried different approaches. One approach partially worked in which I used Widgetlayout and created seperated layout file. I want to know how to style Switch PreferenceCompat using XML(preferebly)

Answer (score 0):

One example would be as below.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/sb"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:track="@drawable/switch_track_330"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_330"/>
```

drawable/switch_track_330

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray3_330" />
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="18dp" />
            <corners android:radius="9dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue_330" />
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="18dp" />
            <corners android:radius="9dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

drawable/switch_thumb_330

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                    <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                    <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```